# Shopify: Global variable data type

Tags: global-variables, shopify, comparison-operators

I'm having an unbelievable amount of difficulty finding out the data type of a global variable in Shopify. My problem could be a matter of scope, but it still shouldn't be difficult for them to tell me a data type. Their tech support says the theme writer should answer it and the theme writer says that Shopify should answer it. IMHO, either of them should be able to answer it. So I would greatly appreciate any wisdom you can provide.

My client is a wholesaler who does not do orders less that $50.00. It should be fairly easy to run a comparison in the variable for the total order (cart.total_price | money_with_currency), but my code is entirely unsuccessful. The code should also allow a retailer to change their order and run the comparison again. I have added every possible combination of parenthesis to the variable and pieces, in case I have a syntax error.

```
        <div class="six columns cart-buttons">                
          {% if cart.total_price | money_with_currency < 50 %}
            <div style="font-weight: bold; color: #900; margin-bottom: 15px;">Your order must be at least $50.00</div>
          {% endif %}              


          {% if cart.total_price | money_with_currency > 50 %}
              <input class="button nice" type="submit" value="{{settings.checkout_text}}" name="checkout" />
                {% if additional_checkout_buttons %}
                  <em>or</em>
                  {{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}
                {% endif %} 
            {% endif %}
           </div>   <!-- end cart buttons div -->
```

Answer (score 1):

See the Shopify docs on [money filters](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/money-filters#money_with_currency). The `money_with_currency` filter may output something like "$1.45 CAD". Maybe try [`money_without_currency`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/money-filters#money_without_currency), which formats the price as a decimal.

**EDIT:**

Looks like `money_without_currency` doesn't work. The code below causes `Liquid error: comparison of String with 50 failed`:

```
{% assign total_price = cart.total_price | money_without_currency %}
{% if total_price < 50 %} ... {% endif %}
```

So, you have 2 options. First, you could convert the output of `money_without_currency` to a number like this:

```
{% assign total_price = cart.total_price | money_without_currency | times: 1 %}
```

Or, compare against `cart.total_price` without a filter (add 2 zeros because `cart.total_price` does not have a decimal place, so $50.00 is 5000 if not formatted with a money filter):

```
{% if cart.total_price < 5000 %} ... {% endif %}
```

Comment: Incredible! {% assign total_price = cart.total_price | money_without_currency | times: 1 %} worked after hours of frustration trying other combinations.
- I assumed that the global variables could be used like other variables, but it seems that Shopify variables also include some processing that has to be run, hence assigning the result to a local variable.
- I believe that Shopify is written in Ruby, so I'm wondering whether this structure is a Ruby thing or a Shopify thing?